# osmf plugin and swf verification

Tags: flash, cdn, osmf

My flash player is osmf based. It loads a osmf plugin and in this plugin it calls "DefaultMediaFactory.createMediaElement(...)" to create a VideoElement and starts to play it. The cdn that hosts the content requires swf verification. Is that the osmf plugin or the player that needs to be swf verified?

Answer (score 1):

swf verification should happen on the player, not the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can depend on the cdn you're using and how they implement swf verification.

As far as I can tell from working with some cdns, you need to verify the module that requests the stream, so the rule of thumb is to verify the module actually doing the playback.

With this said, even if your plugin is the one triggering the request, it is more than possible that if the MediaElement class is in the player, that's what you'd need to verify.